# How to change mouse position in hook

Tags: delphi, mouse, hook

I would like to know how I can change mouse position in MouseProc function. Specifically to keep Y-coordinate the same. This is my function:

```
function HookProc(nCode: Integer; MsgID: WParam; Data: LParam): LResult; stdcall;
var
begin        
  PMouseHookStruct(Data)^.pt.Y:=600;

  Result := CallNextHookEx(Hook,nCode,MsgID,Data);
end;
```

I thought that re-writing the MouseHookStruct Y-coord would do the trick, but apparently not.

Comment: Are you trying to keep mouse at potion Y=600 for ALL applications? is that a good idea?

Comment: This is a basic part which I need to be working. The app is just a small feature for me which I will use for school purposes - it will allow me to draw straight lines (math), so that's that

Comment: You don't *need* to keep the mouse position at y=600 to draw a horizontal line.  For an example, open up MS Paint, select the line draw tool, and try to draw a horizontal line.  Now hold down the shift key and try to draw a horizontal line.

Comment: I know that of course. But if I am plotting a function that is periodic with some curves and horz lines, it would be too slow to keep changing from pen to line mode (I'm doing it in OneNote). Besides, this is not about why, this is about how

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be looking for [`ClipCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) Function. No need to use hooks.

Remark:
The cursor is a shared resource. If an application confines the cursor, it must release the cursor by using ClipCursor before relinquishing control to another application. 
The function confines the cursor to a rectangular area on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`SetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 function.

Comment: If I allow the mouse movement and then move it back, won't it cause the mouse to be kind of 'shaky'?

Comment: @Magicmaster If this is a `WndProc` hook you're doing and the handler is handling `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, then no, it will not appear to move and jump back to the position you set it to (I know exactly what you're talking about but it won't do that). Edit: Oh, if this is a hook via SetWindowsHookEx, then try and see :)